# ¿como hago para que solo se inserten uno o dos datos iguales en un procediemiento almacenado?

Tags: sql-server

tengo este procedimiento almacenado :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertar_horario_pensum]
@id_materia_pensum int,
@id_horario int
AS

BEGIN  
SET NOCOUNT ON;

insert into horarios_pensum (horarios_id, pensum_id) values 
(@id_horario,@id_materia_pensum)

END
```

lo que necesito es que al ejecutarse este sólo me permita insertar uno o dos datos y que después de este límite me muestre un select diciento que no se pueden insertar más datos del mismo tipo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen varias formas, la primera que se me ocurre es:

agregar un columna para la fecha de creación, que guarda la fecha y hora de la creación del registro.

con esto se puede preguntar cuando fue creado el ultimo registro con los dos parametros de entrada del SP.

en el siguiente ejemplo si la diferencia entre la fecha actual y el ultimo registro creado con los dos parámetros ingresados es mayor a 5 minutos se agrega, de lo contrario se ignora (el insert) y muestra el mensaje de que no se puede agregar el registro. (para esto utilizo un datediff  y la variable limit)
. Hay que revisar si el max(fecha_creacion) funciona, de lo contrario conviene ordenar los datos y obtener el ultimo registro de la columna utilizando top 1 y order by fecha_creación DESC. por eso, como digo hay varias formas.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertar_horario_pensum]
@id_materia_pensum int,
@id_horario int
AS

BEGIN  
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @limit datetime

select @limit = max(fecha_creacion) from  horarios_pensum 
where 
horarios_id = @id_horario 
and
pensum_id = @id_materia_pensum

@if(DATEDIFF(minutes,@limit,getdate()) > 5 )
begin

insert into horarios_pensum 
(horarios_id, pensum_id, fecha_creacion) 
values 
(@id_horario,@id_materia_pensum, getdate())

select "registro insertado blablabla"
end
else
begin
     select "no se pueden insertar más datos del mismo tipo"
end


END
```

espero se entienda la idea.

Comment: gracias compañero logré lo que necesitaba hacer